# Ternary expression to execute before null checking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

How can I shoprten the following block by using ternary expression?

```
if(paginator) {
    paginator.pageIndex = 1;
}
```

I try to use this:

```
paginator.pageIndex = paginator ? 1 : undefined
```

But I am not sure if it is a good idea or if there is an elegant way. Because when `paginator` is undefined it seems to be not a good idea to set its property as undefined. So, can I use ternary operator for this scenario?

Comment: Why is the first code need shortening? Note that you can omit the brackets and place it in one line if you think you gain much from saving vertical space `if(paginator) paginator.pageIndex = 1;` however if that gains you anything is arguable at best.

Comment: _"Because when `paginator` is undefined it seems to be not a good idea to set its property as undefined"_ - When `paginator` is not defined then there's no property you can set in the first place o.O

Comment: I VtC because the question in its current form doesn't make sense (see my comment above) and not because answers might be opinion-based.

Comment: @Andreas *what* is OP asking for makes sense to me. Instead of the `if` statement, they want a one-liner. A conditional operator is an attempt of doing that. As you point out, that doesn't work but that's basically what the question is about "how to do this". However, my biggest issue is *why* do it. There are shorter alternatives but whether they are are worth using depends on the why. Also, many similar questions are [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) *at best*. Often they aren't even problems. I agree with POB - for now it's just "how do I format my code better".

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you. Then it is good idea to use as it was used before.

Comment: You can use `paginator && paginator.pageIndex=1`, but not ternary operator, ternary operator is for give value to a variable according a condition.

Comment: @Eliseo I also used it, thanks. it is also useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with your original suggestion.

Why? If paginator is undefined, then "paginator.pageIndex" will cause your code to throw an exception.

In this case I would stick with your original code which will not throw exceptions.